# Rails .first(n), but skip "m" before the n are taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, many-to-many

```
<% current_user.education_experiences.first(4).each_with_index do |exp, i| %>
```

I'm hoping .first(n) can be made into .first(8), .drop_first(4) or something similar.

To add further clarification, on python django you can write custom filters, and then load specific files of filters in specific pythonic .html files (.html.rb in ruby). An example is in the .html you write:

`{% load filters1 %}` at the top of the page

And then where the equivalent ruby would be would be:

`{% for exp in current_user.education_experiences|drop_first:"4" %}`

And then in the `/templatetags/filters1.py` you would write:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def drop_first(values, n):
    return values[n:]
```

And it's as simple as that.

And for the `.first(n)` that I was after in Ruby, there's an inbuilt tag for it in Django that looks like this:

`{% for exp in current_user.education_experiences|slice:"4" %}`

A more relevant example to what most people building stuff these days is probably:

`{% for exp in current_user.posts|slice:"4" %}`

Because nobody knows that my `education_experiences` model was a `education_experiences = models.ManyToMany(Education_Experience, ...)`
field, or in ruby a `has_many :education_experiences` field, it doesn't matter that it was essentially a Resume builder website, but I no longer have the Ruby version of the code, because the functionality and packages weren't there for some things and I not only knew Python better, but I had been doing it for longer and had a lot of my own private pre-written code I could copy from, so building in Ruby took 6 months, but redoing in Python took 1 month.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: like an array [4:array_length] or [n:n+4] in this instance.